# Typescript weird type intersection of `string & {}`

Tags: typescript

on some libs, I often see a TS syntax something like this:

```
type AriaRole = 'alert' | 'tree' | 'treegrid' | 'treeitem' | (string & {});
```

What the mean of `string & {}`?
It's a string intersected with an object.
Does that make sense or maybe a hack?

Comment: That's interesting, it prevents union to be "squashed" to `string` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgSwIYCUD2AbaBeKAfKAciSzmEPyODgggoMOtoHNEATeqmiBYCAW04AKAM7UEAO2ZQAZFADeAXwCUAbgBQoSFAAaUXPKgBtANJRJsRKkwQAugC4oEgK78ARhDhRF6zeGgAYmho+pTEpORhTHRR3KwIHLG0vAKcYohSGlrQAJqhhqbmElBBaA5Orh5ePupsEADGGEg0UPVoEmJQAB72OupAA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks strange, because this type is basically `string`.

But if you wrote `'alert' | 'tree' | 'treegrid' | 'treeitem' | string` then your type would be simplified to just `string`. This would mean if you start writing this code:

```
let role: AriaRole = 'a
```

Then you wouldn't necessarily get useful autocomplete suggestions. As far as Typescript is concerned, `AriaRole` would be `string` so you'd just be writing any string, Typescript wouldn't know that these specific strings would be worth suggesting.

But written with `string & {}`, it doesn't get simplified to `string` and so the whole union doesn't get simplified, and the consequence is that you get autocomplete suggestions for `'alert'`, `'tree'` or so on, while also allowing any other string value.

So the reason for writing the type this way, I think, is to have a type where every string is allowed, but some strings are "encouraged" by autocomplete suggestions. It also means you can see those "encouraged" strings when you hover over the type name.

Comment: This will also allow distribution over union in conditional types (as the union is preserved)

Comment: @AlekseyL. Interesting point which I hadn't considered, but I can't think of a good example where that would be useful. If you have one, please write an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: great answer. So it just for preserving the autocomplete feature.

Comment: @kaya3 yeah, also need to think where to apply this 

Answer (score 0):

To @AlekseyL & @kaya3

So this is the implementation of `(string & {})`:

```
type Theme = 'primary'|'secondary'|'success'|'danger'|(string & {})

interface MyComponentProps {
   theme? : Theme
}
export default function MyComponent(props: MyComponentProps) => ....

<MyComponent theme='primary' />    // choose from the pre defined themes
<MyComponent theme='customDark' /> // or use a custom theme name
```